# Problem installing ar_tools in Catkin

Tags: ar-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I have a question about the installation of **ar_tools** stack in **catkin**.

I will create an example empty project, with ar_tools stack. Following the tutorials..

```
$ source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ catkin_init_workspace
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/
$ catkin_make
$ source devel/setup.bash
```

Once the project have been created and initialized, I get the source https://github.com/xqms/ar_tools (because dont exists a catkin branch in https://github.com/LucidOne/ar_tools source):

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ git clone -b catkin https://github.com/xqms/ar_tools
```

And now, if I try to compile the project:

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/
$ catkin_make
```

I get this error message:

```
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'ar_tools'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ar_tools/ar_tools)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'artoolkit'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ar_tools/artoolkit)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'ar_pose'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ar_tools/ar_pose)
CMake Error at /home/redhome/jonyal/catkin_ws/devel/share/artoolkit/cmake/artoolkitConfig.cmake:141 (message):
  Project 'ar_pose' tried to find library 'ARgsub'.  The library is neither a
  target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project 'artoolkit'?
  Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory containing its code is
  included?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package)
  ar_tools/ar_pose/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

I have tried to compile by hand artoolkits, but nothing happens.

Thank you for your help.
Jonatan AL

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201125/problem-installing-ar_tools-in-catkin/) by [Jonatan AL](https://answers.ros.org/users/21394/jonatan-al/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-01-16

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It just happened to me today also, and I had to compile artoolkit separately first.

```
 $ catkin_make --only-pkg-with-deps artoolkit
```

I don't know the reason, because I've had compiled ar_tools before without experiencing this.

---

Originally posted by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) with karma: 738 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mimpho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22438/mimpho/) on 2015-05-15**:
I tried the same but got dis error while compiling artoolkit, can u help me wid dis?
Performing download step (SVN checkout) for 'ARToolkit'
svn: Can't connect to host 'svn.code.sf.net': Connection refused
make[2]: *** [ar_tools/artoolkit/ARToolkit-prefix/src/ARToolkit-stamp/ARToolkit-download] Erro

**Comment by [Leandro](https://answers.ros.org/users/22435/leandro/) on 2015-05-15**:
I tried what you said, but even after compiling artoolkit separately, when I compile ar_tools I get the same error with ar_pose again.